# Raycast in Unity2D can't seem to find the floor

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm currently trying to use raycast to let my game know when my character is in the air, or more importantly when he is on the ground. A simple raycast should do the trick but no matter what I try it keeps returning false. Both my player and floor have colliders attached, here is the relevant code.

## pragma strict

```
    var leftKey: KeyCode;
    var rightKey: KeyCode;
    var jumpKey: KeyCode;
    var playerSpeed = 7;
    var onFloor = false;
    var distToGround: float;

    function Start () {
        // get the distance to ground
       distToGround = GetComponent.<Collider2D>().bounds.extents.y + 0.1f;
    }
     
     function IsGrounded(): boolean {
       return Physics.Raycast(GetComponent.<Collider2D>().bounds.center, Vector3.down, distToGround, 1 << 8);
     }

    function Update () {
        Debug.Log("" + IsGrounded());
        if (IsGrounded()){
            if(Input.GetKey(leftKey)){
                GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x = playerSpeed * -1;
            } else if(Input.GetKey(rightKey)){
                GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x = playerSpeed;
            } 
            
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey)){
                GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0,380));
            } 
        } else if (!IsGrounded()) {
            if(Input.GetKey(leftKey)){
                GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(-2,0));
            } else if(Input.GetKey(rightKey)){
                GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(2,0));
            } 
        }
    }
```

I've been stuck on this for a while now and I'm pretty sure I'm just an idiot who is missing something simple or I've been reading out of date materials.

Comment: I've had trouble with this and it was because the raycast layer was incorrect. I found that this was the best solution to debug that issue: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/416919/making-raycast-ignore-multiple-layers.html Also, depending on where this script is attached, you could swap Vector3.down for transform.up*-1.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Your `IsGrounded()` function has a typo. It should be `GetComponent<Collider2D>()`, not `GetComponent.<Collider2D>()`
2. Try increasing the value of your `distToGround` float, just in case the RayCast is going in the right direction, but not far enough.

I hope that helps!